# Why is my multiple-key GET query to Cloudant returning all documents?

Tags: json, couchdb, cloudant

Just starting out.

I have a view on cloudant, bywords, that provides a view of all documents and their keywords.  It looks like this:

```
bywords = function(doc) {
    var tokens, re1,
        uniq = function(a) {
            var o = {}, i = 0, L = a.length, r = [];
            for (; i < L; i++) {
                if (a[i] !== '' && a[i] !== ' ') {
                    o[a[i]] = a[i];
                }
            }
            for (i in o) { r.push(o[i]); }
            return r;
        };

    if ( doc.observation && doc.observation !== '') {
        tokens = uniq(doc.observation.split(/( +)|\./));
        if (tokens && tokens.length > 0) {
             tokens.map(function(token) {
                 emit(token, null);
             });
         }
    }
};
```

(I don't think there is a `unique` fn available to me in the design doc, so that view fn defines its own.)

The result of the view looks like this:

```
....
{
 "id": "doc-095141",
 "key": "Vivamus",
 "value": null
},
{
 "id": "doc-102754",
 "key": "Vivamus",
 "value": null
},
{
 "id": "doc-094047",
 "key": "volutpat",
 "value": null
},
{
 "id": "doc-092332",
 "key": "vulputate",
 "value": null
},
....
```

There's one item in the view, for every word in a particular field of the document, for each document.

ok...

Querying by key works nicely. I mean, this:

`https://myserver.cloudant.com/fop/_design/baseViews/_view/bywords?key=%22amet%22`

...returns the expected subset of items from the view.  It's a handful of items, fewer than 10.

On the other hand a multi-key query returns all items in the view. If I do this:

`https://.../_design/baseViews/_view/bywords?keys=%5B%22amet%22%5D`

...then I get every item.  Many many items. Not what I want.

**How can I specify multiple keys in a GET?**

I don't believe I want `startkey` and `endkey`.  I want the items with keys present in the set I specify.

---

ps: I know about [the option to POST a JSON keys array](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Access.2BAC8-Query).  I haven't tried that yet.  From my reading the doc, I should be able to do a GET and specify multiple keys in the query string.

---

**EDIT**

I just tried the POST option.  It works as expected. In other words, this HTTP request:

```
POST https://myserver.cloudant.com/fop/_design/baseViews/_view/bywords 
...headers here...

{"keys":["amet"]}
```

..returns what I expected it to return: a handful of matching documents.

So, I am no longer blocked, but it remains a puzzle to me that the GET / URI-encoded form for specifying keys does not work on Cloudant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having this problem, I think it's an old bug in CouchDB.  Which version of couch are you running?  A `GET` with the `keys` param works for me now in 1.2.0.  IIRC the bug was in 1.0.x

Comment: I am using Cloudant.com .  I don't know what version of CouchDB they are running.

Comment: Just hit the `/` of your server, it will report back the version.

Comment: `{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.2","cloudant_build":"613"}`  So, maybe that bug is still present in Cloudant?  Any chance you have a jira link for that bug?

Comment: Nope, I don't know that I even confirmed it.  Just upgraded and it was gone :)